# Is that possible to have a stateful bean that is not shared between threads?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot

Right now I have a service that runs an algorithm.

I use a Bean to store some data that is needed during the calculations.

Now I want to change the algorithm in a way I can parallelize it so I want to run it in multiple threads. So imagine that I have certain input and I divide it in 2 and then each thread uses the same algorithm I had before to do the calculations of each part.

To do this I want to have that same Bean in each of the threads so I can use it to store the data of each thread.

Is there a way to have one Bean "instance" per thread that doesn't share state with the others?

Comment: You can either create a bean instance for each thread and merge them after all threads are complete, or use a single bean instance shared between the threads which you have made thread safe. The choice of solution will depend on the data structures in the bean.

Comment: Show some code that you've tried.